# What is the main difference between the decorators @Input() and @Attribute() in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I have seen @Attribute() being used in Directives usually as a parameter in the constructor like this:

```
export class EqualValidator implements Validator {
    constructor( @Attribute(‘validateEqual’) public validateEqual: string) {}
    validate(c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {}
}
```

and @Input() used in Components like this:

```
export class UserProfile {
    @Input() user;
    constructor() {}
}
```

And then you can pass data into these variables in the template with property binding in the case of @Input().

What are the main differences between these decorators and when should you use them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Input(): Used to pass values into the directive or to pass data from one component to another (typically parent to child).

@Attribute(): You are able to retrieve the constant value of an attribute available in the host element of component/directive and it has to be used with a parameter of a component’s or Directive’s constructor

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand the explanation of @Input(), but not @Attribute(). What do you mean by constant value of an attribute? Also I don't understand why you would want to use @Attribute() over @Input() in some situations.

Comment: With @Attribute we can map the constant value of an attribute on html to a property on your component.

Comment: What do you mean by constant value? Like a string that can't change? Does it have to be a string? Or can it be a complex object? When would you want to use @Attribute() instead of @Input() ? I still don't understand the difference between them. I understand that one is declared as parameter in the constructor and one is declared as property.

Comment: Please have look at https://plnkr.co/edit/Zemj0H7CHm8JmNpI8qkC?p=preview for a simple example.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but that example did not answer my question.

Comment: @Alex you can only get scalar/string values from the Attribute, for example, if you have a HTML element like <input myAttrib="theValue">

Then in your Directive or Component constructor signature, you can get the value of the attribute 'myAttrib' like this - @Attribute('myAttrib') public myParam, then this.myParam will have the 'theValue'

Comment: So does that mean if the value is a constant, that `@Attribute` should be used because that way the value isn't added unnecessarily to Angular's change detector?

Comment: Since your last question hasn't been answered yet, i will do so for future visitors: yes, the performance is key when it comes to attribute over input - if you know that the value will be constant. for a more detailed version see here: https://netbasal.com/getting-to-know-the-attribute-decorator-in-angular-4f7c9fb61243